# How to use Call() in springmvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to count gender column using conditions like state ,male,female, prefercources. how to write query in spring?I know to fetch data from data base using mapper class but here i only need to count .please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: i got it solution ....:)

Comment: just want to ask I have multiple selection values in string array how to use this in  sql query using where clause